# How to install redis 3.0.7 on Debian 8

Tags: redis

I'm trying to install Redis 3.0.7 (latest stable version at the moment) on Debian 8.

I use this commands :

```
add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server
apt-get update
apt-get install redis-server
```

But when I use `redis-cli info`, I see that version 2.8.14 is installed. What do I miss here? I want the latest stable version to be installed.

Comment: Is this an Ubuntu PPA?

Answer (score 3):

As [terdon suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281026/how-to-install-redis-3-0-7-on-debian-8#comment488866_281026), you are trying to use an Ubuntu PPA on Debian.

If you want to install the latest version of Redis on Debian, you will want to install from source. You can try the following:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test  # Optional
sudo make install
```